# Java RMI has different instantiations on client variables from client itself and from remote calls from server

Tags: java, scope, rmi

We are trying to create a system using Javas RMI. The problem is that a maintained list on the client cannot be accessed from the server using Java RMI. It seems that the RMI connection is handling a copy of the initialized list.

Below is a minimal example using an integer that the client increments every second until it equals 10. The server receives 0 all the time though.

Anyone have any idea what we are doing wrong?

Just run server and the client as a java application.

**ServerDefaultImpl.java**

```java
package rmi;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class ServerDefaultImpl implements EIServerRemote, Runnable {
    ClientRemote client;
    private boolean running = true;

    public ServerDefaultImpl() {
        try {
            LocateRegistry.createRegistry(Registry.REGISTRY_PORT);

            ServerDefaultImpl server = this;
            EIServerRemote stub = (EIServerRemote) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0);

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.rebind("test", stub);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ServerDefaultImpl();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true == running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                if (null != client) { //Client not connected yet.
                    int test = client.test();
                    System.out.println(test);
                    running = test <= 10;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void attachClientListener(ClientRemote client) throws RemoteException {
        this.client = client;
    }
}
```

**EIServerRemote.java**

```java
package rmi;

import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface EIServerRemote extends Remote {
    void attachClientListener(ClientRemote client) throws RemoteException;
}
```

**ClientRemote.java**

```java
package rmi;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.rmi.Remote;

public interface ClientRemote extends Remote,Serializable {
    int test();
}
```

**ClientDefaultImpl.java**

```java
package rmi;

import java.rmi.NotBoundException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry;
import java.rmi.registry.Registry;

public class ClientDefaultImpl implements Runnable,
        ClientRemote {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4846141863099303590L;

    protected EIServerRemote server = null;

    public int test;

    public boolean running = true;

    public ClientDefaultImpl(String serverName) {
        test = 0;
        try {
            connect(serverName);
        } catch (RemoteException | NotBoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ClientDefaultImpl("test");
    }

    public void connect(String serverName) throws RemoteException,
            NotBoundException {
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
        EIServerRemote s = (EIServerRemote) registry.lookup(serverName);
        server = s;
        s.attachClientListener((ClientRemote) this);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true == running) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(test++);
                running = test <= 10;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int test() {
        return test;
    }
}
```

Comment: `test` needs to be volatile in the client.

Comment: It didn't seem to work just by adding the volatile keyword. Trying to make it a Remote object now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems that the RMI connection is handling a copy of the initialized list.

That's correct. The list isn't a remote object, so it is passed and returned via serialization.

Comment: After implementing it as a Remote Object using UnicastRemoteObject it is working. Thank you!